# How to add iPad subview controller to act like a Tab Bar

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app that I just got setup with a split view controller to display blogs on the ipad version of the app.  The current setup is master controller is a table view to show the different articles off the blog, and the detail controller is a view controller with a webview inside used to show the content of the article.  The issue is that I have a few other features in the app, and on the iPhone version, I use a tab bar controller to navigate.  What would be some options to add buttons to the detail controller that would allow me to navigate to the other sections of the app?  I know I can't get a Tab Bar Controller within the Split View Controller so I just need some guidance.

I know that the Engadget app is setup so that when you open in portrait mode, it shows the table view of apps, along with a controller at bottom to go to different things like photos, and when in landscape the table view is on the left and the text of the articles is on the right.  I just want it set up so there is no blank page if you open in portrait mode, and have a feature to view other pages, besides just adding buttons to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you CAN add a tabBarController to your SplitViewController's detail view. Simply create a `UIViewController` that responds to `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` and in the xib file for that controller add a `UITabBarController` object and link it to your UIViewController. In your `viewDidLoad` add the Tab bar controller to the view:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

     ...

     [self addChildViewController:myTabBarController];

     //add the tabBarController view
     [self.view addSubview:myTabBarController.view];

}
```

This `UIViewController` will be assigned to your detail view. this works and I've tried it before. However, whether apple would allow it? i don't know!

**EDIT:**

first of you should never call `viewDidLoad` yourself.

Also, i don't think you need `rootipad` and `detailipad` as long as the controllers are linked to the SplitViewController in the xib file.

in your `RootViewiPad` (master) add the following inside its `viewDidLoad` :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    ...

    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        //select the first row to load 
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

        //NOTE, I'm assuming that selecting the cell will load the detail view.
        //if that is not the case, you need to do what ever you need to load the 
        //detail view.
    }
}
```

if you want this behavior to happen every time (not only on first load) then add the code to the `-(void)viewWillAppear` method instead.

Comment: Don't know if I'd want to try something that could end up getting rejected by Apple.  Maybe a better option would be to somehow get the Detail view (the one that shows the whole screen in portrait mode) to get the most recent article at launch time, and display it at launch instead of being blank?  However, not sure how to go about doing that either.

Comment: im not sure if this will get rejected by apple.. if their guidelines dont strictly mention that you can't have a tabBarController in a splitView then the above would be fine.. for your other solution its quiet simple.. since the master view controller is a tableViewController, check for the orientation on `viewDidLoad` then simply have `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollOption:` select the first option to load the detail view.

Comment: I'm not for sure what you were referring to doing here, but here is what I tried.  On the AppDelegate didFinishLaunching I setup the Master Controller (Table View) as a controller, and told it to run a method in the Master Controller code.  This method is then told to select the entry from the array at index 0.  The problem is that for some reason the parsing does not happen and so the array is not created and it crashes with error index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: can you post the code for how you are creating the `UISplitViewController` and how you assign the master controller to it?

Comment: Sure, see here for the AppDelegate.h:
[link](http://pastebin.com/BuDEkXjC)
For the AppDelegate.m:
[link](http://pastebin.com/HHwZHUSU)
Then I went to IB MainWindow.xib, added a SplitViewController, and hooked up all connections

Everything behaves correctly...Can rotate to landscape, select an article, and it displays in the Detail view...just want the Detail view to auto load the first story so that if a user opens in portrait mode, instead of a blank screen they get first story.

Comment: I checked it out.  I threw in an NSLog to make sure that it was detecting it in portrait mode, and the log showed up in console, however it still was not loading anything.

Comment: I think the reason it may be doing this is that the viewDidLoad calls a method which begins the parsing process, and so that doesn't happen until later on, so the array is still empty at that point.

Comment: Yea, I just put a log in one of the table view sections, and it never got called while in Portrait mode

Comment: that makes sense, try wrapping the code in a method `-(void)selectOnPortrait` for example, then call it from viewDidLoad with a delay like this `[self performSelector:@selector(selectOnPortrait) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]`

Comment: Tried that and not working, and even gave it a full minute to make sure everything was parsed before it tried...I could upload my project and see if I'm missing something obvious.  My popover isn't working either.  It will display the exact same TableView that I use when in landscape mode, but selecting an article does nothing, so I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: Did finally get the portrait thing solved.  Because of how the app was setup, I needed to provide the detail controller with the entry property of the indexPath at row:0.  Once I did that, the code you had worked great.  If you could edit it to show in the selectonportrait method:
        ~//select the first row to load 
        WebViewController2 *detailViewController = 
        self.webViewController2;
        RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:0];
        _webViewController2.entry = entry;
        [detailViewController performSelector:@selector(viewWillAppear:)];~

Comment: I'll just start a new thread regarding popover, but if you edit your answer to what I listed, I'll mark it as accepted.